# Right trapezoid outline shape (with transparency)

Tags: css, transparency, css-shapes

I'm trying to emulate an angled path line similar to [**this image**](http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs9/i/2006/058/7/b/Alien_Technology_by_calamarain.png).

The way I'm doing it is using two trapezoid shapes, and overlapping one with another that would be the same as the background as seen in [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNESN/).

But I realized I want the **rest** of the shape to be **transparent** instead of being able to overlap other objects.

The core is just a little bit of CSS, an *outlineMaker* div inside of a *rightTrapezoid* div.

```
.rightTrapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
.outlineMaker {
    border-bottom: 80px solid white;
    border-left: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
    height: 20px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

Is there a neat and concise way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete example following nice using @Feng Huo tip.


HTML Markup

```
<div class="trapezoidLine1">
    <div class="trapezoidLine2"/>
</div>
<div class="trapezoidLine3">
    <div class="trapezoidLine4"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.trapezoidLine1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
}
.trapezoidLine3 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:45px;
  width: 207px;
  height: 2px;
    background:blue;
  }
.trapezoidLine2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 47px;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(80deg);
}

.trapezoidLine4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;

  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(270deg);
}
```

Try the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/TNW63/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to force this way to work with a twist somehow. I gave it a couple minutes of thought and realized DUHHHHHHH, I can just do [**this**](http://jsbin.com/OciHeQO/1/):

```
<div class="trapezoidLine1">
  <div class="trapezoidLine2"/>
</div>

.trapezoidLine1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.trapezoidLine2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  left: 200px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

Herp a derp...