# How can I get my text inside of my CSS shape?

Tags: css

I am trying to learn how to use the `:before` to put text into my shape, however I am stuck and not sure how it actually works.

Here is the basic setup:

```
<div class="trapezoid"> Hello </div>
```

with

```
div {
    border-top: 100px solid blue;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  height:0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However, the text appears below the shape.  Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/om2wf48t/

Comment: That's because the css code you have is using border-top to create the main body of the shape and border-top will push the content you put inside to the bottom I would reconsider your approach and use the method from the answer on this question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718587/is-it-possible-to-style-a-div-to-be-trapezoidal

Comment: Before I found that link I was playing around with your fiddle. Here is what I did: https://jsfiddle.net/om2wf48t/2/

Comment: ...also looks like you are missing the `content` property inside your `:before`

Comment: or simply wrap your text in a span, set position to absolute and add a negative top margin, a dirty approach but works! [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/om2wf48t/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example code: http://codepen.io/skylarjhdownes/pen/mAPwKW

So, basically what's happening here is that you're making a div that has the word "Hello" in it, and then applying a couple of css rules to all the divs on your page.

One very simple answer that will put your text inside the shape is "Change `border-top` to `border-bottom`.", but that will invert your trapezoid and doesn't actually use the trick you're trying to learn.

The main thing preventing you from using the trick is, as Ankith pointed out, that you're missing the `content` property in your `div:before` block.  Check out [MDN's examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) for `before:`, they all have one.  If you remove the text "Hello" from your `<div>` tag and put `content:"Hello.";` in your `div:before` then you'll be halfway there, but your text won't have moved.  Next you'll need to change the top property to have a value other than zero so that your text will move.  `top:-20px` or even better, `top:-2em` will put your text inside of your trapezoid.

Bonus:
There are several things in your original code that aren't really doing anything.  If you delete everything in the div:before block, for example, it won't change your page.  Neither would deleting `class="trapezoid"`.

Your `class="trapezoid"` code is a good idea though.  If you change `div` to `div.trapezoid` in your css, then `class="trapezoid"` will be relevant, and you can control which divs in your page have trapezoids on them.